# API changes in kentico 9

Tags: c#, kentico

I have upgraded my Kentico project from 8.2 to 9. In my custom code I am getting the following error:

> 'SaveAction' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

This is my code:

```
CurrentMaster.HeaderActions.AddAction(new SaveAction(this));
```

[API changes documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-9/7443) suggests to change it to:

```
CurrentMaster.HeaderActions.AddAction(new SaveAction());
```

Is this a correct implementation?

Comment: Have you tried it or built your project/website?  Does it compile?  Does it give you expected results?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a correct way to use it. You'll probably also want to implement the behavior of the save action:

```
HeaderActions.ActionPerformed += HeaderActions_ActionPerformed;

private void HeaderActions_ActionPerformed(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        // Save object
        case ComponentEvents.SAVE:
          // Your code here
          break;
    }
}
```

Have a look at `CMS\CMSModules\Ecommerce\Pages\Tools\Products\Variant_New.aspx.cs` for instance.